# Laravel sort by pivot table column

Tags: laravel, join, pivot

I am trying to sort an eloquent query in laravel by a column from the pivot table.

Basically as long as the product is favorited by the user, it is added to the pivot table, and it should first show the favorited ones, and then the remaining ones. Since I will be using foreach in the blade.

products table contains these columns:

```
id, category, product_name, priority, status, created_at, updated_at
```

users table contains these columns:

```
id, name, email, created_at, updated_at
```

with the following in the users model:

```
public function favorites()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Products::class, 'favorites', 'user_id', 'product_id')
                ->withTimeStamps();
}
```

favorites table contains these columns:

```
id, user_id, product_id, created_at, updated_at
```

In the controller, the eloquent query is currently:

```
$productinprogress = Products::all()
    ->sortByDesc("priority")
    ->where('status', 'inprogress');
```

I am just confused as to how to tackle this.

Your help is appreciated. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like bellow:

```
$productinprogress = Products::all()
   ->where('status', 'inprogress')
   ->sortByDesc("priority");
```

and if you want an efficient solution using eager loading and loading favorites too, use following code

```
 $productinprogress = Products::all()
    ->with('favorites')
    ->where('status', 'inprogress')
    ->sortByDesc("priority");
```

Comment: BadMethodCallException
Method with does not exist.

Comment: I cannot see any priority  field in your database, can you try to change priority to any other  field which is present there

Comment: It is actually available, forgot to put it in the top. So priority field is available.

Comment: Can check the updated code, hopefully that would be your solution

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make two queries to avoid loading duplicate products, first one for favorite products, second one should be some thing like this:

```
Products::all()->sortByDesc("priority")->where('status', 'inprogress')->whereNotIn('id', $favorite_products);
```

and then in the blade file, you make two foreach, first one for favorites, and 2end for others.